# File not reading in Java

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a simple program that reads a file that contains, line-by-line, the number of things and each of their coordinates. It then uses those coordinates to tell you where to build a fence in the least amount of space.

E.g. The file reads:

```
3
1 0
0 3
4 0
```

The code I have works, but it will not read and operate on the file i'm reading in. Any suggestions on how to make it work?

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Things{

    final static int MIN_THINGS = 2;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        Scanner testFile = new Scanner(new FileReader("test3.txt"));
        int nThings = testFile.nextInt();

        if (nThings < MIN_THINGS) {
            System.out.println("Invalid input. " + MIN_THINGS + " things required to build a fence. ");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        int xMin, xMax, yMin, yMax;

        xMin = xMax = testFile.nextInt();
        yMin = yMax = testFile.nextInt();

        for (int i = 1; i <= nThings - 1; i++) {
            int x = testFile.nextInt();
            int y = testFile.nextInt();
            if (x < xMin)
                xMin = x;
            if (x > xMax)
                xMax = x;
            if (y < yMin)
                yMin = y;
            if (y > yMax)
                yMax = y;
        }

        System.out.print("Fence Coordinates: {(" + xMin + "," + yMin + "), ");
        System.out.print("(" + xMax + "," + yMin + "), ");
        System.out.print("(" + xMax + "," + yMax + "), ");
        System.out.println("(" + xMin + "," + yMax + ") ");
    } 
}
```

Comment: At some point you need to use `nextLine` to remove the trailing new line characters which will exist between the lines in the file.  Personally, I use `nextLine` to read a line from the file and then use a second `Scanner` to parse the line

Comment: Make sure your file is at `System.out.println(new File("test3.txt").getCanonicalPath());` - Otherwise, change `"test3.txt"` to the full path to your file. Alternatively, read it from the user's home folder.